# How do I test a single file using Jest?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I am able to test multiple files using Jest, but I cannot figure out how to test a single file.

I have:

- Run `npm install jest-cli --save-dev`
- Updated `package.json`: `{ ... "scripts": { "test": "jest" } ... }
- Written a number of tests.

Running `npm test` works as expected (currently it runs 14 tests).

How do I test a single file, e.g. test `app/foo/__tests__/bar.spec.js`?

I have tried running `npm test app/foo/__tests__/bar.spec.js` (from the project root), but I get the following error:

> npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/node_modules/app/foo/**tests**/bar.spec.js/package.json'

Comment: Use `npx jest Foo.test.js`  use `--watchAll` if you want to watch changes in the background e.g `npx jest  --watchAll Foo.test.js`

Comment: And for watching, can also pass like this: `npm test -- bar.spec.js --watchAll` / `yarn test -- bar.spec.js --watchAll`.

Comment: No one worked for me. Check  my workaround https://stackoverflow.com/a/75404447/3957754 for linux users

Comment: No one worked for me. Check my workaround for linux users https://stackoverflow.com/a/75404447/3957754

Comment: in latest versions of jest you could use `it.only()`, `describe.only()`, etc in which case it will just execute that single test without having to pass a file or filter parameter.

Answer (score 970, accepted):

### Since at least 2019:

`npm test -- bar.spec.js`

### In 2015:

In order to run a specific test, you'll need to use the `jest` command. `npm test` will not work. To access `jest` directly on the command line, install it via `npm i -g jest-cli` or `yarn global add jest-cli`.

Then simply run your specific test with `jest bar.spec.js`.

**Note**: You don't have to enter the full path to your test file. The argument is interpreted as a regular expression. Any part of the full path that uniquely identifies a file suffices.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working for me. Running `jest bar.spec.js` gives `jest: command not found`. I've confirmed Jest is installed (`npm list -g jest` shows `jest@0.1.37`). FWIW, when I run using `npm test` it uses `jest-cli`.

Comment: Yes, `jest-cli` is the right module, install it globally `npm install -g jest-cli`. `jest` in npm is... [something else](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest)

Comment: Thank you. Installing `jest-cli` globally allowed me to run `jest bar.spec.js`.

Comment: That's incorrect. npm test working does not mean that jest is installed globally. It just means jest is installed within your project.

Comment: Like @ChiedoJohn said. To run it without installing globally, you can run this from the root of your app: `node_modules/.bin/jest args`

Comment: is there any alternative method for running jest tests apart from command line?? , as if i make post request to my existing project rest api's its will give me CSRF token problem.

Comment: It is ridiculously hard to run a single test file because of the regex file search. I always end up renaming the file that I need to test to something like: `bar.specTEST.js` and then run `npm test bar.specTEST.js`. And renaming back when I am done

Comment: If you're using the default jasmine setup you can focus a single test by using `fit` instead of `it`.

Comment: @eremzeit That's useful, but only applies if you have a single test file. It will still run other test files that match the test pattern.

Comment: With the advent of npx, you can run `npx jest bar.spec.js` instead of installing jest globally. It will also read the jest version from your devDependencies

Comment: this is not the best answer. Check out the answers of @cabaji99 and Nicholas Carey for better options

Comment: And how do we run code coverage just for a single test in Jest?

Comment: You can use `npm test` like `npm test -- bar.spec.js`

Comment: I was able to run it by doing ```yarn jest FILE```

Comment: Thank you! npm test -- filename works great and is saving me so much time now. Best answer

Comment: this answer is partially wrong though. If you run using `npm test -- bar.spec.js` it will execute other files that match that name, not just `bar.spec.js`. For instance, it would also run tests inside of `prefix-bar.spec.js`

Answer (score 555):

All you have to do is chant the magic incantation:

```
npm test -- SomeTestFileToRun
```

The stand-alone `--` is *nix magic for marking the end of options, meaning (for NPM) that everything after that is passed to the command being run, in this case `jest`. As an aside, you can display Jest usage notes by saying

```
npm test -- --help
```

Anyhow, chanting

```
npm test -- Foo
```

runs the tests in the named file (`FooBar.js`). You should note, though, that:

- Jest treats the name as case-sensitive, so if you're using a case-insensitive, but case-preserving file system (like Windows [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS)), you might encounter what appears to be oddness going on.
- Jest appears to treat the specification as a prefix.

So the above incantation will

- Run `FooBar.js`, `Foo.js` and `FooZilla.js`
- But *not* run `foo.js`

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I get the same error when running this: `npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '<path to project>/node_modules/<name of file>/package.json'`

Comment: is there any alternative method for running jest tests apart from command line?? , as if i make post request to my existing project rest api's its will give me CSRF token problem.

As how will i setup jest testing to my existing project ?? so that it will start serving request using '/rest-api' instead of  'http://localhost:8000/rest-api'

Comment: @SuyogSawant: that's not a comment. it's a question on its own. You should should ask it here on StackOverflow.

Comment: in my case simple `npm test ToDoForm.test.js` worked while `jest ToDoForm.test.js` didn't

Comment: your second point about case sensitivity does not match the incantation you provide above.

Comment: For windows you will need to type double backslashes for the file path. Ex: yarn run test src\\tests\\actions\\auth.test.js

Answer (score 91):

If you install the Visual Studio Code plugin *Jest Runner*,

[image]

You will have *Debug*/*Run* options above every `describe` and `it`.

[image]

You can open your test file in Visual Studio Code and click on one of those options.

Comment: Jest Runner did not work for me in some test cases, Then I switched to Jest extension for VSCode and it worked for me. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Orta.vscode-jest

Answer (score 64):

To run an individual test:

```sh
npm test -t ValidationUtil # `ValidationUtil` is my module `ValidationUtil.spec.js`
```

`-t` - after it, put a *regular expression* containing the test name.

Answer (score 57):

Using `npm test` doesn't mean Jest is installed globally. It just means "test" is mapped to using Jest in your `package.json` file.

The following works, at the root level of the project:

```
npx jest [file or directory]
```

`file or directory` can be the test file you want to run or the directory containing multiple files.

Comment: a shortcut to execute binaries in `node_modules/.bin` is to use `npx` command. For instance `npx jest [args]`

Comment: worth pointing out that @Aerohil didn't miss that; the command did not exist in 2016; I updated the answer

Comment: This one is the only one that worked for me. All the other flavours, using npm, ran ALL tests, despite output saying that a regex was applied, and seemed restrictive...
Also, you may just run `npx jest <pattern>`, even if your file lies within subfolders inside of tests.

Answer (score 55):

If you use [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/), you can add the `.spec.js` or `.test.js` file directly after:

```
yarn test src/lib/myfile.test.js
```

This is the part from my `package.json` file with Jest installed as a local package (removed the relevant parts):

```
{
...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "testw": "jest --watch",
    "testc": "jest --coverage",
...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^18.1.0",
    ...
  },

}
```

Comment: You can also use `yarn test SomeRegexHere` to save typing, e.g. `yarn test MyClass`. However, note that as of Dec 4, 2021, the regex matches against the absolute path, so your pattern may match folder names that contain your source tree. See https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8226

Answer (score 27):

You could use the file name with `npm test --`:

```
npm test -- fileName.jsx
```

Answer (score 18):

We are using [nrwl-nx](https://nx.dev/web) with [Angular](https://angular.io/). In this case we can use this command:

```
npm test <ng-project> -- --testFile "file-name-part"
```

Notes:

- `npm test` will run the test script specified in `package.json`:
  `"test": "ng test"`
- `--`: tells npm to pass the following parameters to the test script (instead of consuming them)
- Thus the rest of the cmd will be passed to [ng test](https://angular.io/cli/test)

  - `<ng-project>` is the name of a project in `angular.json`

    - when you omit this parameter, the `"defaultProject"` (specified in `angular.json`) will be used (so you must specify it, when the test is not in your default project)
  - Next we must check which builder is used:

    - In `angular.json` navigate to `"project"` - `"<ng-project>"` - `"architect"` - `"test"`
    - and check the `"builder"`, which in our case is: `"@nrwl/jest:jest"`
  - Now that we know the builder, we need to find the available cmd-line parameters

    - On the command line, run `npm test <ng-project> -- --help` to see all available options
    - Or check the [online documentation](https://nx.dev/packages/jest/executors/jest)
  - One of the options is `--testFile` which is used here

Answer (score 14):

To run a specific test in a specific file:

```
yarn test -f "partial-filename" -t "as split node"
```

`npm test`, or `jest` can replace `yarn test`, depending on your preferred JS bundler.

This would only attempt to find tests in files that contained `some-partial-filename`, and within those files, the test would need to have a `describe` or `it` directive that mentions "as split node", for example

```
// In cool-partial-filename.js
describe("with a less indented sibling", () => {
  it("should create a new check-list-item with the same indent as split node", () => {
    console.log("This would run with the invocation above");
  })
})
```

Answer (score 13):

### With a package.json script

With `"scripts": { "test": "jest" }` in package.json:

```
npm test -- foo/__tests__/bar.spec.js
```

### Using jest-cli directly

Globally-installed:

```
jest foo/__tests__/bar.spec.js
```

Locally-installed:

```
./node_modules/.bin/jest foo/__tests__/bar.spec.js
```

### Using `--testPathPattern`

The [`--testPathPattern` option](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--testpathpatternregex) has the equivalent effect of passing paths as unnamed positional arguments to jest-cli. See [normalize.ts](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/95f49691d3472d8187640f1b703209b93c2bcecc/packages/jest-config/src/normalize.ts#L456-L461).

```
./node_modules/.bin/jest --testPathPattern foo/__tests__/bar.spec.js
```

### Testing two or more specific files

Separate filenames with commas or spaces:

```
./node_modules/.bin/jest foo/__tests__/bar.spec.js,foo/__tests__/foo.spec.js
```

```
./node_modules/.bin/jest foo/__tests__/bar.spec.js foo/__tests__/foo.spec.js
```

Pass `--testPathPattern` multiple times:

```
./node_modules/.bin/jest --testPathPattern foo/__tests__/bar.spec.js --testPathPattern foo/__tests__/foo.spec.js
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are running `npm >= 5.2.0` and you have installed Jest locally as a `devDependencies` with `npm i -d jest`, you can run Jest on a particular file by doing `npx jest /path/to/your/spec.js`.

Answer (score 8):

Use this command:

```
npx jest test --runTestsByPath <path-to-file>
```

Answer (score 7):

At that time, I did it by using:

```
yarn test TestFileName.spec.js
```

You shouldn't put in the complete path. That works for me on a Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 6):

It can also be achieved by:

```
jest --findRelatedTests path/to/fileA.js
```

Reference ([Jest CLI Options](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#running-from-the-command-line))

How can that be achieved in the Nx monorepo? Here is the answer (in directory `/path/to/workspace`):

```
npx nx test api --findRelatedTests=apps/api/src/app/mytest.spec.ts
```

Reference & more information: *[How to test a single Jest test file in Nx #6](https://github.com/satminav/nx-qa/issues/6)*

Answer (score 6):

If you dont want to install jest globally you can use

```
npx jest foo.test.js
```

Answer (score 5):

This is how I dynamically run tests on a specific file without restarting the test.

My React project was created as `create-react-app`.

So it watches test for changes, automatically running test when I make changes.

So this is what I see at the end of the test results in the terminal:

```
Test Suites: 16 passed, 16 total
Tests:       98 passed, 98 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.048s
Ran all test suites.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

Press <kbd>W</kbd>

```
Watch Usage
 › Press f to run only failed tests.
 › Press o to only run tests related to changed files.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.
```

Then press <kbd>P</kbd>

```
Pattern Mode Usage
 › Press Esc to exit pattern mode.
 › Press Enter to filter by a filenames regex pattern.

 pattern ›

 Start typing to filter by a filename regex pattern.
```

This is after I wanted to run the 'index.es6.js' file in the 'Login' folder:

```
Pattern Mode Usage
 › Press Esc to exit pattern mode.
 › Press Enter to filter by a filenames regex pattern.

 pattern › login/index

 Pattern matches 1 file
 › src/containers/Login/index.es6.test.js
```

That's how I run tests on a specific file.

Answer (score 5):

The simple way is to run a single unit test file, is inside the root folder run the command in the terminal.

```
npm test <fileName.test.js>

// For example
npm test utils.test.js
```

I have also tried the Jest Runner Extensions for Visual Studio Code, and it works great.

Answer (score 5):

Jest and Jest Runner are super useful VSCode extensions when you working on jest.

[Jest](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Orta.vscode-jest#features) An automatic test runner

[Jest Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=firsttris.vscode-jest-runner) Adds "Run | Debug" code lens above the test to run or debug a single test.

[image: "Run | Debug" code lens]

Comment: Link-only responses are fine as a Comment, but are unacceptable as answers. Answers must be self contained, and exact code necessary to solve the issue must be embedded. Links are perfectly acceptable, BUT relevant info from the link must be embedded. No-one wants to click on blind links, and, importantly, your response becomes useless if the site becomes unreachable, or the content changes.

Answer (score 5):

The below command worked for me. 
`npx jest -i file-name`

No need to specify complete path of the file, filename is sufficient.

Edit :
Found another way to do it. 
`npm run test:functional -i file-name` for Functional Test 
`npm run test:integration -i file-name` for Integration Test

Answer (score 5):

Do this if you are using **yarn**

```
yarn test nameofthefile
```

eg:

```
yarn test file.test.js
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution that works:

`yarn test -g fileName` or

`npm test -g fileName`

Example:

`yarn test -g cancelTransaction` or

`npm test -g cancelTransaction`

More about test filters:

```
Test Filters
--fgrep, -f Only run tests containing this string [string]
--grep, -g Only run tests matching this string or regexp [string]
--invert, -i Inverts --grep and --fgrep matches [boolean]
```

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any need to pass the full path. Just use a regular expression pattern.

See *[--testLocationInResults](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#--testnamepatternregex)*.

```
yarn jest --testNamePattern my_test_name
yarn jest -t=auth
yarn jest -t component # This will test all whose test name contains `component`

yarn jest --testPathPattern filename # This will match the file path
yarn jest filename # This will match the file path, the same with above
```

Answer (score 3):

For example on ReactJs Project, I installled Jest-cli globally by this command

```
npm i -g jest-cli
```

then in the root folder in my project, I can use this command to run the test for this single file <<Todo.test.js>>

```
jest Todo.test.js
```

It is working fine from my end. I hope it will working from our also.

Answer (score 2):

I just installed Jest as global, ran `jest myFileToTest.spec.js`, and it worked.

Comment: this worked great super simple.  thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just use this command to run and check the coverage of the particular file.

```
yarn run test Index.js -u --coverage --watchAll=false
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- Option 1: Command line. You can run the following command

  ```
  node '/Users/complete-path-to-you-project/your-project/node_modules/.bin/jest' '/Users/complete-path-to-you-project/your-project/path-to-your-file-within-the-project/your-file.spec.ts'
  ```

  This avoids you to install Jest globally. You use the jest used by your project.
- Option 2: If you are using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) you have a great plugin to do this: [Jest Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=firsttris.vscode-jest-runner). It allows you not only to run tests file by file, but even specific suites and specs just by a right click on the tests you want to run.

Answer (score 1):

With Angular and Jest you can add this to file *package.json* under "scripts":

```
"test:debug": "node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --runInBand"
```

Then to run a unit test for a specific file you can write this command in your terminal

```
npm run test:debug modules/myModule/someTest.spec.ts
```

Comment: But how can I connect it to vscode for example, for debugging?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli) documentation:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest path/to/my-test.js"
  }
```

Run this with

```js
 npm run test
```

Answer (score 1):

With a package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --coverage",
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
```

The following worked for me:

```
npm test -f comm -- -t=first
```

It will find all files containing 'comm' in its filename and only run tests containing 'first' in the found files.

Answer (score 0):

**Jest** will use what you pass as a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) pattern. That it will match for.

If you want to run a specific test file, then the best way to do it is to use the precise full path to it. (You can too specify a certain relative path like (src/XFolder/index.spec.ts)).

The easiest way to provide the full path being in the directory and in Linux is:

```
jest $PWD/index.spec.ts
```

Note the use of the variable **$PWD**.

[image]

For Windows! (to be updated)

Answer (score 0):

```
import LoggerService from '../LoggerService ';

describe('Method called****', () => {
  it('00000000', () => {
    const logEvent = jest.spyOn(LoggerService, 'logEvent');
    expect(logEvent).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Usage:

```
npm test -- __tests__/LoggerService.test.ts -t '00000000'
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is it supposed to achieve and is the first part the content of file *LoggerService.test.ts*?

Answer (score 0):

For [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) users, the simple alternative is to use,

```
npm test -t <name of the spec file to run>
```

NestJS comes preconfigured with the regex of the test files to search for in case of Jest.

A simple example is -

```
npm test -t app-util.spec.ts
```

(that is my .spec file name)

The complete path need not be given since Jest searches for *.spec* files based on the configuration which is available by default in case of NestJS:

```
"jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

Comment: OP isn't asking about NestJS, they are asking about Jest.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

if you want to see a complete report like this with coverage by file and without the global coverage you can setup your environment the next way, this is a single test file but with super powers

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "cov": "npm run test \"$src\" -- --coverage --collectCoverageFrom=\"$(echo $src | sed 's/.spec//')\"",
},
```

jest.config.js

```
{
    coverageReporters: ['lcov', 'text-summary']
}
```

Usage:

```bash
#  src=your_path_file npm run cov
$  src=src/components/Footer/Footer.spec.tsx npm run cov
```

Answer (score -2):

"test": "jest api/ds_server/ds_server.test.js"

Comment: An explanation would be in order.