# Debug a single test in Jest

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I have many jest tests, within many test suites, within many test files.

I need to isolate and debug a single test.

I'm debugging via `node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest`, so other solutions involving watch mode are too complicated.

How can I skip all tests except the one I need to debug?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run only ONE test with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446626/run-only-one-test-with-jest)

Comment: i clarified the question to differentiate it from the others — this question is about debugging, and requires a solution that is compatible with the `node --inspect-brk` method of debugging

Answer (score 10):

jest handles this in two steps

1. **isolate your test file** by running jest with the [testPathPattern (jest docs)](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/cli.html#testpathpattern-regex) command line argument

   ```
   node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest --testPathPattern="integration.test"
   ```

   here `integration.test` is supplied as a regular expression to filter for the correct test file
2. **isolate your test function**
   there are two ways to do this

   - one way is to use the [testNamePattern (jest docs)](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/cli.html#testnamepattern-regex) command line argument

     ```
     node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest --testNamePattern="host events"
     ```

     here `host events` is supplied as a regular expression to filter for the correct test suite name
   - alternatively, you can add `.only` to your test function:

     - so that `test("object works", async() => {/*...*/})`
     - becomes `test.only("object works", async() => {/*...*/})`

Answer (score 7):

I am using VSCode for debugging and in launch.json add to *runTimeArgs* a *testPathPattern* as your folder name:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [{
    "name": "Debug Jest Tests",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "--inspect-brk",
        "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
        "--runInBand",
        "--testPathPattern=<NameOfTheFolder-you-want-to-test-without-this-angle-brackets>"
    ],
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
    "port": 9229
}]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VSCode, Jest extension might come in handy.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Orta.vscode-jest

Answer (score 1):

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=firsttris.vscode-jest-runner

Another extension. This one uses CodeLens so there are Run|Debug links above each test:

[image: jest runner unit test]