# Ignore certain files when running `npm test`

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, npm, jestjs

Currently `npm test` is running all files that has `.test.js` extension. I would like some files to be ignored. Where do I configure that option? I tried

```
 "jest": {
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
            "src/App.test.js"
        ]
    },
```

in package.json.
I don't see any difference.

Comment: you need to use `testPathIgnorePatterns`

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests#configuration As per create-react-app documentation, only these 4 properties can be overridden.

Answer (score 32):

`package.json` only allows you to override the following Jest configuration with [`create-react-app`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#configuration)

```
"jest": {
  "collectCoverageFrom": [],
  "coverageThreshold": {},
  "coverageReporters": [],
  "snapshotSerializers": []
}
```

### Solution 1

Eject Create React App and configure by using `testPathIgnorePatterns`.

### Solution 2

You can still override Jest's configuration by passing the `--testPathIgnorePatterns` option to `react-scripts test`.

For example:

```
"test": "react-scripts test --testPathIgnorePatterns=src/ignoredDirectory --env=jsdom"
```

Comment: What if I want to run tests only for the files in certain directories?

Comment: "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --testMatch=src/App.test.js". I tried this so that only App.test.js runs. But npm test gives 0 matches. @tobias

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446626/run-only-one-test-with-jest/44446669 which might help :)

Comment: Note that using `testPathIgnorePatterns` as a cli argument breaks the ability to run one test with either `npm test Testname` or `npm test -- -t TestName`.

Answer (score 7):

You might be tempted to use `testPathIgnorePatterns` as a cli argument, but note this causes unexpected side effects, in that it breaks the ability to run single tests with `npm test TestName` or `npm test -- -t TestName`.

This is because, as far as i can tell, `testPathIgnorePatterns` is incredibly greedy, in that any argument after the `testPathIgnorePatterns` argument will be used as a value for `testPathIgnorePatterns`.

For example:

If I have the following set in my `package.json`:

```json
"test": "react-scripts test --testPathIgnorePatterns=e2e",
```

And then run: `npm test MyTest`

Then the resulting command is: `react-scripts test --testPathIgnorePatterns=e2e "App"`

And jest will be ignore both `e2e` and `App`!

A workaround I have found is to not use the `testPathIgnorePatterns` cli arg, and instead use the `testMatch` jest config.

Let's say I want to ignore all files in an `e2e` directory, then I could use the following regex:

```json
"testMatch": [
  "<rootDir>/src/(?!e2e)*/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  "<rootDir>/src/(?!e2e)*/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
]
```

Or if i wanted to only include tests in a certain directory, I can use:

```json
"testMatch": [
  "<rootDir>/src/modules/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  "<rootDir>/src/modules/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
]
```

Comment: [Here are the docs on `testMatch`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testmatch-arraystring) for anyone curious about it.

Comment: Additionally, `testPathIgnorePatterns` is configurable in `package.json` without any need to change the `npm test` command.

Comment: According to https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#configuration, `testPathIgnorePatterns` is not configurable in `package.json`