# How do I test a single file using yarn workspaces?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I know I can [run a single test file using Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725955/how-do-i-test-a-single-file-using-jest).

I also know I can run all the tests in a single workspace with:

```
yarn workspace @mycompany/somepackage test
```

But how would I run a single test file within a workspace?

I have tried:

```
yarn workspace @mycompany/somepackage test packages/somepackage/src/index.int.test.ts
```

and also:

```
yarn workspace @mycompany/somepackage test src/index.int.test.ts
```

As I am unsure whether the 'test' expects paths relative to the workspace or not. Both fail with:

```
No tests found, exiting with code 1
```

I am using Yarn v1.22.7 and my tests use Jest.

How do I test a single file using Yarn workspaces?

Answer (score 2):

You can run this command:

```
yarn jest packages/somepackage/src/index.int.test.ts -c packages/somepackage/jest.config.js
```

you should change packages/somepackage/jest.config.js by exact path of your jest.config.js